# Interceptor or filter for rest endpoint

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

I just complete my python flask 101 [tutorial here](https://realpython.com/blog/python/token-based-authentication-with-flask/). All went well and now I have flask server running successfully.

However, now I want to add another rest endpoint `/products` that should return a sample list of products in this case. Since it is a `jwt` based implementation, I would like to make sure the user request is intercepted by `/status` or `/auth` api before it is executed.

Is there a way to reuse current implementation rather than copy pasting the whole thing again for new rest endpoints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this.

The first one is a little implicit. It's possible to specify methods that should be called before and after requests.

```
@app.before_request
def authenticate():
    # logic for verifying tokens
    pass
```

The authenticate function would be called for each route.

[Documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.before_request)

Documentation

On the other hand you can create a view decorator:

```
from functools import wraps

def requires_auth(view):
    @wraps(view)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        # logic for verifying tokens

        return view(*args, **kwargs)

    return decorated
```

and then you can wrap any view that should be protected with this decorator E.g

```
@requires_auth
@app.route('/myroute')
def my_route():
    # Normal logic for view
    pass
```

It depends on your use case, if your Flask app is an API where most of the views are protected you can go with the `.before_request` method on the other hand if you have a lot of pages that are public. You can use the decorator.